# Conditional Counting in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to count conditionally on one column, here's my code.

```
spark.sql(
      s"""
         |SELECT
         |  date,
         |  sea,
         |  contract,
         |  project,
         |  COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'ABC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS abc,
         |  COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'DEF' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS def,
         |  COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'ABC' OR type = 'DEF' OR type = 'GHI' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS all
         |FROM someTable
         |GROUP BY date, seat, contract, project
      """.stripMargin).createOrReplaceTempView("something")
```

This throws up a weird error.

`Diagnostic messages truncated, showing last 65536 chars out of 124764:`

What am I doing wrong here?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is that weird error?

Comment: @PeterHull I updated the question. The diagnostic gets truncated and it doesn't actually say what the error is.

Comment: Which variable are you doing the count on?

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes I'm counting on type

Comment: Have you tried to add ```WITH ROLLUP``` after the groupings since you are doing multiple groupings.

Comment: I think thats just warning, can you post screenshot after executing above sql ??

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to get count of type = 'ABC', type = 'DEF' etc per grouping condition.

**If this is the case then COUNT will not give you desired results but would give same result for each case for a group.**

**It seems you can use SUM instead of COUNT.**

**SUM will add all 0 and 1 will give you correct count.**

Still if you want to resolve the error you are getting, please paste the error and if possible some data you are using to create data frame.